# Django + Nginx + Gunicorn example.com works but www.example.com returns Bad Request (400)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to make it possible to access www.example.com aswell as example.com which works fine but it returns Bad Request 400:

Django:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['librestock.com', 'www.librestock.com']
```

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name librestock.com www.librestock.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/david/StockSearch/stocksearch;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/david/StockSearch/stocksearch/stocksearch.sock;
    }
}
```

any ideas for debugging and troubleshooting this?

Comment: Do you have set in settings.py these values by accident? SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
when not using SSL secured connection?

Comment: Kindly take a look at your gunicron log ; also check if it is working or not; if you cannot make it out please paste the nginx and gunicorn logs here.